# How array of object update in React.useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      price: 999,
      title: "Watch",
      qty: 1,
      id: 1,
      img: "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/military-style-watch-picture-id650233226?s=612x612",
    },
    {
      price: 20000,
      title: "Samsung F42",
      qty: 1,
      id: 2,
      img: "https://images.samsung.com/is/image/samsung/p6pim/in/sm-e426bzahins/gallery/in-galaxy-f42-5g-8gb-ram-sm-e426bzahins-514504593?$684_547_PNG$",
    }]);
```

I want to update the qty by onClick and passing this data from component 1 to component 3 via component 2. So, what will be the statement for setProducts to update the qty.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, what have you tried already on your own?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass this function with parameter Id as callback to onClick

```
function increaseQuantity(Id){
  let res = products.map((obj) => obj.id === Id ? {...obj,qty:obj.qty+ 1} : obj)
  setProducts(res);
}
```

example -

```
<button onClick={() => increaseQuantity(item.id)}></button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way. Pass the `method` as `props` on that component.

Read more about [react components-and-props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

```js
const { useState, memo } = React;

const Parent = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    {
      price: 999,
      title: "Watch",
      qty: 1,
      id: 1,
      img:
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/military-style-watch-picture-id650233226?s=612x612"
    },
    {
      price: 20000,
      title: "Samsung F42",
      qty: 1,
      id: 2,
      img:
        "https://images.samsung.com/is/image/samsung/p6pim/in/sm-e426bzahins/gallery/in-galaxy-f42-5g-8gb-ram-sm-e426bzahins-514504593?$684_547_PNG$"
    }
  ]);

  const increaseQuantity = (productId) => {
    const updateProducts = products.map((product) =>
      product.id === productId ? { ...product, qty: product.qty + 1 } : product
    );
    setProducts(updateProducts);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <Product
          key={product.id}
          {...product}
          increaseQuantity={increaseQuantity}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Product = memo((props) => {
  const { id, title, qty, price, increaseQuantity } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name : {title}</p>
      <p>Price : {price}</p>
      <button onClick={() => increaseQuantity(id)}>{qty}</button>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```